# Check if two URL strings are the same PHP

Tags: php, regex, yii

How to check if two URL strings are the same for example

http://example.com

http://example.com/

https://example.com/

http://example.com/#

All the above url points to same page

Suppose i am having a directory of urls in my database and i am adding a url to the database which is already present. how can i validate for uniqueness for the above scenario using PHP.

Comment: I would almost argue that the https variant is NOT the same.

Comment: @Fluffeh but the content inside the url is same rite

Comment: Yeah, but that's also pretty much saying that ftp:// would be the same.

Comment: @fuzionpro No. Try going to `http://google.com/`. You will find NO content, as it redirects you to https.

Comment: @Kolink dont't see it in the perspective of a Bot just think as a user

Comment: If you want to see it as a user then you need to act like a user and actually fetch the URL and see if you end up with the same content or at least are forwarded to the same endpoint. Just looking at two different URLs that's impossible to tell.

Comment: @deceze just tell me if my directory lists both http:// google.com and https:// google.com don't you think that's a kind of duplicate urls in my directory which finally points to same webpage

Comment: So you really want to compare only the *domain* instead of the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break down the URLs into parts and compare those that must match for your definition of "the same".

For example:

```
function areUrlsTheSame($url1, $url2)
{
    $mustMatch = array_flip(['host', 'port', 'path']);
    $defaults = ['path' => '/']; // if not present, assume these (consistency)
    $url1 = array_intersect_key(parse_url($url1), $mustMatch);
    $url2 = array_intersect_key(parse_url($url2), $mustMatch);

    return $url1 === $url2;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/cDW4bQ)**.

Comment: Don't mind me, just as I had the answer ready, you posted yours, so I inserted my example code grabbed off PHP.net for completeness.

Comment: @Fluffeh: I edited over that because it was really not what I intended to post. Please allow people a little time to shape their answer in the future.

Comment: No worries, I very rarely do that, just had the code pretty much ready to post when I got a "1 New Answer" message. Still garnished a +1 from me.

Comment: @Jon your example now shows all false. Can you please check it again otherwise i have to undo the accept answer

Comment: @fuzionpro: I was investigating a little more; the answer and example are now both up to date and work correctly.

Comment: I agree in general about `parse_url`, but this answer is a mess.

Comment: @pguardiario: Would you care to suggest an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to check if URL is same.
**Attention**: This function check if GET query is same too!

```
function isSameUrl($urlPrimary, $urlSecondary){
    $parsedPrimary = parse_url($urlPrimary);
    $parsedSecondary = parse_url($urlSecondary);
    if($parsedPrimary["scheme"] != $parsedSecondary["scheme"]){
        return false;
    }

    if($parsedPrimary["host"] != $parsedSecondary["host"]){
        return false;
    }

    //Compara se ambos estão setados
    if(isset($parsedPrimary["path"]) == isset($parsedSecondary["path"])){
        //Verificar se estão setados = true
        if(isset($parsedPrimary["path"], $parsedSecondary["path"])){
            if($parsedPrimary["path"] != $parsedSecondary["path"]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    //Compara se ambos estão setados
    if(isset($parsedPrimary["query"]) == isset($parsedSecondary["query"])){
        //Verificar se estão setados = true
        if(isset($parsedPrimary["query"], $parsedSecondary["query"])){
            parse_str($parsedPrimary["query"], $queryPrimary);
            parse_str($parsedSecondary["query"], $querySecondary);

            ksort($queryPrimary);
            ksort($querySecondary);

            if(json_encode($queryPrimary) != json_encode($querySecondary)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```